# sbt - Scala - Brew - MacOS - Unable to connect to sbt shell at all: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: macos, scala, sbt

So I'm just trying to get a project set up using JDK 15 / SBT 1.5.4 / Scala 2.13.6 all of which have been installed via brew on MacOS.

However before I even attempt to build via intellij etc.  I'm unable to connect to the sbt shell via a normal terminal.

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.4 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 15.0.2)
[info] loading global plugins from /Users/user/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.swoval.runtime.ShutdownHooks
        at com.swoval.runtime.ShutdownHooks$1.run(ShutdownHooks.java:25)
```

I've tried reinstalling all three dependancies a few times and cleared the cache but still nothing.  I'm guessing something isn't configured right because it's unable to even connect to the shell.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've just followed the install steps on the sbt docs and the only requirements are JDK 11 or 8 and sbt itself.  I've removed scala / JDK15 and re-downloaded JDK 11 via SDK-man this time and i'm still having the same issue.

EDIT 2: I've removed the `.sbt` directory and reinitiased and now `sbt` command is showing more output, hopefully this helps a little more.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.swoval.runtime.ShutdownHooks
    at com.swoval.runtime.NativeLoader.loadPackaged(NativeLoader.java:143)
    at com.swoval.runtime.NativeLoader.loadPackaged(NativeLoader.java:174)
    at com.swoval.files.apple.FileEventMonitorImpl.<clinit>(FileEventMonitors.java:127)
    at com.swoval.files.apple.FileEventMonitors.get(FileEventMonitors.java:47)
    at com.swoval.files.ApplePathWatcher.<init>(ApplePathWatcher.java:258)
    at com.swoval.files.ApplePathWatcher.<init>(ApplePathWatcher.java:194)
    at com.swoval.files.ApplePathWatchers.get(ApplePathWatcher.java:331)
    at com.swoval.files.PathWatchers.get(PathWatchers.java:84)
    at com.swoval.files.FileTreeRepositories.get(FileTreeRepositories.java:64)
    at com.swoval.files.FileTreeRepositories.get(FileTreeRepositories.java:32)
    at sbt.internal.nio.FileTreeRepositoryImpl.<init>(FileTreeRepositoryImpl.scala:46)
    at sbt.internal.nio.FileTreeRepository$.default(FileTreeRepository.scala:40)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$setupGlobalFileTreeRepository$1(Main.scala:985)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$doLoadProject$5(Main.scala:974)
    at sbt.Project$.setProject(Project.scala:501)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:974)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:912)
    at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:150)
    at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:145)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:189)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$processCommand$5(MainLoop.scala:245)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.process$1(MainLoop.scala:245)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:278)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$5(MainLoop.scala:163)
    at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.runCmd$1(State.scala:289)
    at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.process$extension(State.scala:325)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$4(MainLoop.scala:163)
    at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:163)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:144)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:119)
    at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:27)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:112)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:51)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:42)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:218)
    at sbt.xMain$.$anonfun$run$11(Main.scala:133)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at scala.Console$.withIn(Console.scala:230)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withIn(Terminal.scala:560)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.$anonfun$withStreams$1(Terminal.scala:350)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:167)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.$anonfun$withOut$2(Terminal.scala:550)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at scala.Console$.withErr(Console.scala:196)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withOut(Terminal.scala:550)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withStreams(Terminal.scala:350)
    at sbt.xMain$.withStreams$1(Main.scala:87)
    at sbt.xMain$.run(Main.scala:121)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.java:56)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:46)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$run$1(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:176)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.swoval.runtime.ShutdownHooks
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.swoval.runtime.ShutdownHooks
        at com.swoval.runtime.ShutdownHooks$1.run(ShutdownHooks.java:25)
```

EDIT3: Tried creating a new user and just downloading sbt and still getting the same issue.  Will attempt completely removing Java as it seems to be the culprit and reinstalling.

Comment: What is your project SBT version?

Comment: @GaëlJ 1.5.4, I'm just trying to follow the steps [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html).  So this isn't even with a proper project yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Boris's suggestion the issue lied in the installation version of Java.

There are two versions for AdoptOpenJDK, .j9 an .hs as seen below if you are using sdk-man as a package manager:

```
AdoptOpenJDK | >>> | 16.0.1.j9    | adpt    | installed  | 16.0.1.j9-adpt
             |     | 16.0.1.hs    | adpt    |            | 16.0.1.hs-adpt
             |     | 11.0.11.j9   | adpt    |            | 11.0.11.j9-adpt
             |     | 11.0.11.hs   | adpt    |            | 11.0.11.hs-adpt
```

For some reason the OpenJDK version `.hs-adpt` shows this issue for every version but the `.j9-adpt` version works fine.

TLDR: Install the `.j9-adpt` version of Java that you need otherwise `.hs-adpt` is not working for me with `sbt version 1.5.4`.

Comment: glad to hear what source problem lied on the java version side, thank you for publishing correct answer

Comment: You may mark your answer as correct also for the rest members of community

Comment: @BorisAzanov Only able to mark as correct from tomorrow so I'll do it then.  However my colleague who has the exact same Java SDK / SBT version and Scala version is able to connect just fine... I guess this is a work around for now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason - you are using wrong Java JDK for Mac OS with M1 chip. You need to install proper Java JDK version, I use sdkman for that.

1. Install sdk man:

```sh
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

2. set up sdk man to not use `rosetta2_compatbile` versions:

```sh
vim .sdkman/etc/config
```

and set `sdkman_rosetta2_compatbile=false`

3. choose java JDK from the list:

```sh
sdk list java

================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
 Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Azul Zulu     |     | 16.0.1       | zulu    |            | 16.0.1-zulu
               |     | 11.0.11      | zulu    |            | 11.0.11-zulu
               |     | 8.0.292      | zulu    |            | 8.0.292-zulu
 BellSoft      |     | 16.0.1       | librca  |            | 16.0.1-librca
               |     | 11.0.11      | librca  |            | 11.0.11-librca
               |     | 8.0.292      | librca  |            | 8.0.292-librca
 Java.net      |     | 18.ea.3      | open    |            | 18.ea.3-open
               |     | 18.ea.2      | open    |            | 18.ea.2-open
               |     | 18.ea.1      | open    |            | 18.ea.1-open
               |     | 17.ea.28     | open    |            | 17.ea.28-open
               |     | 17.ea.27     | open    |            | 17.ea.27-open
               |     | 17.ea.26     | open    |            | 17.ea.26-open
               |     | 17.ea.25     | open    |            | 17.ea.25-open
================================================================================
```

and install it using command `sdk install java IDENTIFIER`, i.e.:

```sh
sdk install java 16.0.1-zulu
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not using an M1 Chip! Just standard Intel i9 so the JDK 15 I've downloaded via SDKman should work fine... My java_home is set too  `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home`